# Add custom scope with gcc and gprof

Tags: c++, c, gcc, profiler, gprof

I am profiling my C++ program, but I would like to profile specific parts of my functions, as for-loops, some parts of some functions. By compiling with `-pg`, I can only see the samples at a function level. Is there a way to add custom scopes for profiling with GCC and GProf ?

For instance, something like this:

```cpp
int a = 0;

for (int i =0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
    __attribute__("custom-profiler-scope=inside_the_for")
    {
    // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Line_002dby_002dline.html ?

Comment: else you can still create sub functions.

Comment: Line by line profiling is good, but is less readable and doesn't appear in a flame graph.

Comment: gprof can create flame graphs?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I use CLion to generate the flame graph, I compiled with -pg and assume CLion used `gprof`, but it uses `perf`.